# Pass data (e.g. log message) from processor to Slack or LogMessage processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Suppose I want have a processor to send a Slack message and I want to reuse it from many other processors. E.g. one might need to send "file received" while another might send "failed to unzip file", etc. I'd rather have a single `PutSlack` processor and set the `Webhook Text` property to `#{logPrefix} -- ${message}`. That way all of the other processors can use this single processor to post a message in the Slack channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a single `PutSlack` is enough, you can configure `PutSlack` processor properties to dynamically evaluate their values from the incoming FlowFile attributes since all the properties `Supports Expression Language`.