# Apache Nifi LogMessage and PutSlack Processors

Tags: apache-nifi, el

I have a simple flow: GenerateFlowFile -> FetchGCSObject (on failure) -> LogMessage -> PutSlack.

In PutSlack for the Webhook Text, I have the value of Dynamic Message: ${"Log message"}. However, in my Slack channel, I see Dynamic Message:

Not for sure what I'm doing incorrectly, any help is appreciated.

This answer [Pass data (e.g. log message) from processor to Slack or LogMessage processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264702/pass-data-e-g-log-message-from-processor-to-slack-or-logmessage-processor) seems to suggest that I can use Expression language. I've tried ${'Log Message'}, ${"Log Message"}, ${"Log message"}, ${'Log message'}, ${Log Message}, ${message}, ${"message"}, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried: ${log-message} and ${"log-message"} and those did not work. I tried that based on the code found here: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.22.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/LogMessage.java.

Note that I am able to pass down properties from the GenerateFlowFile and PutSlack utilizes those values.

Comment: What are your exact attributes that you want to Write down in Webhook Text Property in PutSlack processor?

Comment: I want to do something: ${log-message} - failure in #{source_desc}. Please investigate.

The log-message should come from the LogMessage Processor, the source_desc comes from the Parameter Context and that works.  I've also tried putting in attributes in the GenerateFlowFile Processor and outputted them in the PutSlack processor.

Comment: According to [Apache Nifi Docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.22.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage/) , **LogMessage** Processor has no **Writes Attributes** and it does not change the content of its incoming flowfile.Anyway, if you want to concat multiple values from flowfile attributes or parameters to make a whole value for **Webhook Text** Property in **PutSlack** Processor, you can do:
${log-message} - failure in #{source_desc}.
Pay attention to your processor's **Writes Attributes** and your defined variables.

Comment: Let's say that the Log Message attribute is: "Hello World" and source_desc: CSV; the message would be: " - failure in CSV." is what would be outputted to my Slack channel by doing as you suggest.

Comment: Yes exactly. If your **${LogMessage}** is empty or not defined before **PutSlack** Processor, the Value will be " - failure in CSV."

Comment: Thank you so much, definitely the Write attribute is not on this processor and doesn't add it to the flow file, so I could do an UpdateAttribute and pass that to the LogMessage processor which then will get passed to the PutSlack processor. Learning about Nifi has been fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LogMessage Processor doesn't have any Write attributes, which doesn't add anything to the flowFile. If one wanted to just have a single place to reuse a log message, the option would be to use: UpdateAttribute -> LogMessage (use expression language for the new attribute) -> PutSlack (use expression language for the new attribute).

Thank you Saeed Mousazadeh for conversing with me to help better understand Nifi